# Iteration with v-for by using a function which returns an array in vueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, loops, vuejs2, v-for

I have a parent component that calls a child component, see the child component below, and the parent component passes it an array of authors

Array incoming with parent component

```
[
   {
      "name":"James T. Kirk",
      "series":[
         {
            "title":"myserie1",
            "kind":"comedy"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"Spock",
      "series":[
         {
            "title":"Star Trek"
            "kind":"action"
         },
         {
            "title":"The Next Generation"
            "kind":"comedy"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"Jean-Luc Picard",
      "series":[
         
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"Worf",
      "series":[
         
      ]
   }
]
```

**child** component

```
<template>
   <div v-for="(auth,i) in allAuthors" :key="auth.id" class="d-sm-flex mt-8 align-start">
      // here i call my allAuthors method
      <div>
         <div class="">
            <p>{{auth.name }}</p>
            <p>{{auth.series[i].title}}</p>
         </div>
         <div class="py-4">{{auth.series[i].kind}}</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</template>
<script>
   export default {
     name: "MyListItem",
     props: {
       users: []
     },
     data () {
       return {
         author:[]
       }
     },
     created: function() {
       this.author = this.allAuthors
       console.log(this.author);
     },
     computed:{
     },
     methods: {
       allAuthors() {
         let newArr = this.users.find(x => x.series.length === 0)
         return newArr
       }
     }
   }
</script>
```

I want to iterate on the child component on the table coming from the parent component by filtering the table of the parent component in a method and call this method in the `v-for`.
I want to filter the arrays to have only an array whose series exist (different from empty) i.e. whose series property contains at least one element. Then use this array in the `v-for`.
problem it doesn't work.

How can I do it please

Answer (score 0):

You can create `computed` property:

```js
Vue.component('MyListItem', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <div v-for="(auth, idx) in allAuthors" :key="idx" class="d-sm-flex mt-8 align-start">
         <div class="">
            <p>{{auth.name }}</p>
            <ul>
              <li v-for="(serie, i) in auth.series" :key="i">
                <p>{{ serie.title }}</p>
                <div class="py-4">{{ serie.kind }}</div>
              </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
     </div>
   </div>`,
  props: {
    users: {type: Array}
  },
  computed: {
    allAuthors() {
      return this.users.filter(x => x.series?.length > 0)
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
       {"name":"James T. Kirk", "series":[{"title":"myserie1", "kind":"comedy"}]},
       {"name":"Spock", "series":[{"title":"Star Trek", "kind":"action"}, {"title":"The Next Generation", "kind":"comedy"}]},
       {"name":"Jean-Luc Picard"},
       {"name":"Worf", "series":[]}
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <my-list-item :users="items" />
</div>
```

Comment: hi @Nikola Pavicevic, i added a computed  property like allAuthors, but i have error in the console "Error in the render : TypeError: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length' ... at VueComponent.computedGetter) "

Comment: @ln3106 hey mate, that's because you have some object where there is no series array, so you can use `x.series?.length` I updated my answer please take a look